# Oracle - How to use a function inside an escape with q

Tags: sql, oracle, function, select, escaping

I know that I can escape strings in a statement like this:

```
select 'That''s a really funny ''joke''' from dual; --returns: That's a really funny 'joke'
```

Or like this:

```
select q'[That's a really funny 'joke']' from dual; --returns: That's a really funny 'joke'
```

Both are working fine.

Let's say I need to escape a string exactly in that select statement and I also need to use a function.

```
select q'[myfunction(somestringvariable)]' from dual;
```

Of course this only returns "myfunction(somestringvariable)"

As said, I need to escape the results of the function (can't be done inside the function, escape needs to happen in this select statement).

Can I use the function somehow inside a string escaped with "q"?

Thanks!

Comment: Why? The quotes inside the function result will be properly passed. It's only when you write SQL literals you need to bother.

Comment: There are no single quotes allowed on the place where I need to make the select - so if the function returns a text with single quotes, I need to escape them.

Comment: No, you don't. Column/result values need no escaping. Only literals need escaping.

Comment: The result of this select is used in a script (let's say I can't change this script for now). If the script finds a single quote in the result of the select, it throws an error. q'[somestringvariable]' works fine in the script, but in this case I also need to use a function with somestringvariable

Comment: OK, I see. Try `REPLACE(myfunction(somestringvariable), '''', '''''')`

Comment: @Hurt: [Edit] the question and provide a [example] that demonstrates the **actual** problem. This smells like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: If the result of `select q'(something with 'single quote')' from dual` is ok for you (to be precise: for the consumer of this result), then plain result of the function call should be ok too, because both return a `varchar2` *value*, not a string literal that has to be processed by parser to become a SQL value. Otherwise your requirement is not clear. Please note, that in `q'(..)'` brackets are not a part of the value, but a delimiter (that's why plain function call should be sufficient)

Comment: Thanks @jarlh - this solved it! We were using REPLACE(myfunction(somestringvariable), '''', '') before to get rid of the single quotes, but I didn't thnk about generating 2 single quotes in the same way so that they can be escaped correctly :-) How can I upvote a comment as correct answer instead of an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To double single quotes in the function result:

```
REPLACE(myfunction(somestringvariable), '''', '''''')
```

Comment: Thanks! This takes the result of the function and replaces every single single-quote with 2 single-quotes, which are escaped correctly in a select afterwards. Sorry for not being that clear what's needed initially (only wrote "Let's say I need to escape a string exactly in that select statement").

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not support template literals.

---

Just use:

```sql
SELECT myfunction(somestringvariable) FROM DUAL;
```

or, if the function does not return a string:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(myfunction(somestringvariable)) FROM DUAL;
```

---

If you want to concatenate a quoted string literal and a function result then use string concatenation.

```sql
SELECT q'[That's a really funny 'joke']'
       || myfunction(somestringvariable)
FROM   DUAL;
```

Comment: There are no single quotes allowed on the place where the select needs to be used. If the function returns a text with single quotes, this will fail (as the single quotes are still in the result of the function). I need to escape the return value of the function in the select in some way.

Comment: @Hurt Your top two examples in the question have single quotes. There is no difference to the output from those examples and the output from a function (or a string concatenated with a function); if "where the select needs to be used" (which is something you have not defined before so we cannot know about that requirement) works for the top two examples in your question then all the examples in the answer should also work. If they don't then you need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69852748/edit) the question to give a complete [MRE] with **ALL** the details of the problem.

Comment: Yes, I only said "Let's say I need to escape a string exactly in that select statement" - this wasn't very clear, sorry. I already got the correct answer in another comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69852748/oracle-how-to-use-a-function-inside-an-escape-with-q#comment123476304_69852748

Comment: And I also said "As said, I need to escape the results of the function (can't be done inside the function, escape needs to happen in this select statement)."